# How to prove a lower bound of n * log(n) for this simple algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

The question is how many times does this algorithm produce a meow:

```
KITTYCAT(n):
   for i from 0 to n − 1:
      for j from 2^i to n − 1:
         meow
```

So The inner loop has a worse case of n, but it only runs log(n) times because even though the outer loop runs n times, whenever i > log(n) the inner loop never runs, so you have O(n * log(n)).

However, since I can't assume a best case of n for the inner loop, how do I prove that the algorithm still has a best case of n * log(n)?

Answer (score 2):

When *i* > log<sub>2</sub>*n* the start value of the inner loop is higher than its end value. Depending on how you interpret it, this either means that the inner loop counts down, or that it does not run at all.  If you interpret it as counting down, then it gets very big indeed and ends up dominating, and you have **Ω**(2<sup>*n*</sup>), which is not what you seem to be looking for.

If instead you assume the inner loop goes away, then this code is really

for *i* from 0 to log<sub>2</sub>*n*:
     for *j* from 2<sup>*i*</sup> to *n* - 1:
          meow

giving you **Ω**(*n*log*n*)

---

If you're asking how to prove that last step, you can calculate the exact number of iterations -- the inner loop iterates n times, then n-1 times, then n-2, then n-4, etc all the way down to 0.  So the *exact* complexity (at least when n is a power of 2) is

*n* + *n*-1 + *n*-2 + *n*-4 + ... + *n*-*n*/4 + *n*-*n*/2 + *n*-*n*

or

*n*log<sub>2</sub>*n* - 1 - 2 - 4 - ... - *n*/4 - *n*/2

which converges to

*n*log<sub>2</sub>*n* - *n*

which is asymptotically equivalent to *n*log*n* as *n* -> ∞

Comment: I understand this. I’m asking about big omega, the lower bound.

Comment: @decheftw: since we can actually calculate an exact complexity here, the analysis for big-O and big-Omega is the same